# Return value from different sheet based on row and column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having two sheets in excel.
Sheet 1 (Below table can be located anywhere in the sheet)

[image]

and Sheet2

[image]

I would like to automatically add  value to Sheet2 based on Value$ (column) and Name/SID (row)

Was trying to use INDEX with MATCH, however it wasn't able to search whole Sheet array.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C68:J68, MATCH(Sheet2!E6,Sheet1!C54:J54,0))
```

This one was working, however I would like to use it this way.
So it would search whole document and locate the exact text (which is unique)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:J100, MATCH(Sheet2!Value$,Sheet1!A1:J100,0), MATCH(Sheet2!Name$,Sheet1!A1:J100,0))
```

A1:J100 is array where the text might be found.

Also tried to use VLOOKUP, but wasn't working either.

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!B3,Sheet1!A1:J100,MATCH(Sheet2!A4,Sheet1!A1:J100,0),0)
```

Sheet2!B3 = Value1 from table

Sheet2!A4 = Name from table.
Getting #N/A error

Comment: Would there be any issue in adding a helper row to concatenate the conditional values that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem: in sheet 2, I've added the two following formulae and everything is working fine:

```
=Sheet1!B2:G2
=Sheet1!B4:G4
```

As a result, all columns from "B" to "G" get filled in (this might be a behaviour, caused my my latest Excel version, Excel 365).

Comment: Main thing is, we don't know the exact position of Value1 or Name in the sheet. Therefore I need to look for the whole sheet array A1:J100 and when those two conditions met, return the value. 

If using B2:G2, it means, I know which row is the Value1 located. However we don't, therefore we need to search the entire sheet. 

Any idea how to achieve it?
So it will search all Rows in the sheet until it finds Name (probably done by VLOOKUP, but instead of returning the column number, it will search for columns until it find Value1 and get the value from the cell. Not sure if it is clear now.